# About AlarmManager and the way it is saved

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

I'm making an app that uses an Alarm service. I'm still learning how it works but one thing is very unclear and explained nowhere.

Say you create an Alarm when you launch your app. The alarm is saved somewhere because it needs to trigger even when your app is not running, right?

If so, how can I get this alarm when relaunching my app, so I don't create a new one everytime and have an infinity of alarms stored somewhere?

If not, how does it work? I was thinking about using a database or a json file but I have a feeling it's not necessary.

In my MainActivity class, I have this code to check if the alarm exists already (this code is obviously wrong)...

```
AlarmReceiver alarm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(alarm != null){
                alarm.cancel();
            }
            alarm = new AlarmReceiver(MainActivity.this);
        }
    });



}
```

I have set a BroadcastReceiver for when the device is rebooted (as explained in the android tutorial)

```
public class SampleBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
        new AlarmReceiver(context);
    }
}
}
```

This is the AlarmReceiver class itself:

```
public class AlarmReceiver {
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

public AlarmReceiver(Context context){
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            1000 * 60 * 20, alarmIntent);
    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, SampleBootReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

}

public void cancel(){
    alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
}
}
```

And the AlarmBroadcastReceiver that simply launches a notification (which works):

```
public class AlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    new NotificationMessage(context);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The alarm is saved somewhere because it needs to trigger even when your app is not running, right?

Correct.

> how can I get this alarm when relaunching my app

You don't. It's a write-only API.

> so I don't create a new one everytime and have an infinity of alarms stored somewhere?

Only create an alarm when it is needed, not on every run of your app.

Beyond that, use an equivalent `PendingIntent` to an existing alarm when calling the `AlarmManager` methods to replace that alarm (or using `cancel()` to cancel the alarm).

> I was thinking about using a database or a json file but I have a feeling it's not necessary.

You need enough information in persistent storage to know what to do when the alarm goes off. You also need enough information in persistent storage to know what alarms are needed, to handle reboots, when you have to reschedule your previously-scheduled alarms.

Comment: "Beyond that, use an equivalent PendingIntent to an existing alarm when calling the AlarmManager methods to replace that alarm (or using cancel() to cancel the alarm)." Is it possible to do that solely in my AlarmReceiver class? If I can't access my previously set alarm, then how can I change it?

Comment: @zuokuok: "Is it possible to do that solely in my AlarmReceiver class?" -- Presumably. An equivalent `PendingIntent` is the same operation (activity, service, broadcast), the same ID (2nd parameter to `getActivity()`, etc.), and an equivalent `Intent`. An equivalent `Intent` matches on the routing characteristics (component, action, categories, data, MIME type), but does not have to match on extras. "then how can I change it?" -- create an equivalent `PendingIntent` and schedule a new alarm using it, which will replace the old alarm.

Comment: Is it correct that the way my class is written will override the current alarm set, as my pendingIntent is always made the same?

Comment: @zuokuok: It looks good. You can use **`adb shell dumpsys alarm`** to see the outstanding alarm events, to confirm exactly what you have scheduled.